# Can Strapi be installed on a shared server like Dreamhost?

Tags: strapi, dreamhost

Painfully aware I may be "doing it wrong" but I'm heavily invested in the Dreamhost system, and am playing around with the "shiny new thing" of Strapi, and curious if it can be deployed on a dreamhost shared server (not VPS)?

I don't see any tutorials online, so I think not...

Comment: You are correct. Shared hosting is not likely to give you the permissions you'll need to install node + strapi + all the other dependencies you'll need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally not, but NodeJs can be installed onto Dreamhost's Shared hosting

The configuration is not very simple, the performance in shared hosting is not great...  cost-benefit? 
Imho it is not suitable for production and I don't recommend it.

You can read these articles to deepin this topic:
 https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/217185397-Node-js-overview